MongoDB Docker Container Startup Warnings: tcmalloc and vm.max_map_count issues
I'm running a MongoDB container using Docker Compose and encountering startup warnings related to tcmalloc and vm.max_map_count. I've set these values correctly on my host machine, but the container doesn't seem to inherit them.
Setup:
My Docker Compose file:
  mongo:
    build: image
    container_name: mongo
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME: root
      MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD: TO_CHANGE
    ports:
      - 0.0.0.0:27017:27017
    volumes:
      - mongo_data:/data/db
      - mongo_ssl_data:/etc/letsencrypt
      - keys:/keys
    command: >
      mongod --tlsMode allowTLS
            --tlsCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/db0.starknet.id/cert.pem
            --tlsCAFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/db0.starknet.id/fullchain.pem
            --tlsAllowConnectionsWithoutCertificates
            --replSet rs0
            --keyFile /keys/mongo_keyfile
    depends_on:
      certbot:
        condition: service_healthy

My Dockerfile:
FROM mongo:8.0.0

ENV GLIBC_TUNABLES=glibc.pthread.rseq=0

I've set the following on my host machine (ubuntu 24):
root@ashur ~ # sysctl vm.max_map_count
vm.max_map_count = 262144
root@ashur ~ # cat /sys/kernel/mm/transparent_hugepage/enabled
always [madvise] never
root@ashur ~ # cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness
0

Warnings
The server generated these startup warnings when booting
2024-09-21T09:22:31.052+00:00: For customers running the tcmalloc-google memory allocator, we suggest setting the contents of sysfsFile to 'always'
2024-09-21T09:22:31.052+00:00: For customers running the updated tcmalloc-google memory allocator, we suggest setting the contents of sysfsFile to 'defer+madvise'
2024-09-21T09:22:31.052+00:00: We suggest setting the contents of sysfsFile to 0.
2024-09-21T09:22:31.052+00:00: vm.max_map_count is too low

Why aren't these settings being inherited by the container, and how can I resolve these warnings? I tried setting them in the Dockerfile but this doesn't seem to work of to be the reasonable solution.
